# Python . Script to run exe file

Tags: python

I want to execute an exe file in script which requires command like this in commandline C:\pathtotool.exe -2 c:\data .

how can  i do this in python in windows. Os.system does not work

Answer (score 3):

```
import subprocess

# Call your exe
subprocess.call('C:\pathtotool.exe -2 c:\data ')

# if you want to print output 
p = subprocess.check_output('C:\pathtotool.exe -2 c:\data ')
print p
```

or

```
import os
os.system(start 'C:\pathtotool.exe -2 c:\data ')
```